# Pass JWT into Angular 4 app / Redirect after saving JWT

Tags: angular, angular-router

How can I pass a JWT into an Angular 4 app, save the token, and then navigate to the home page?  I'm trying the following syntax but I'm worried that relying on `ngAfterViewInit` is not the correct way of doing this...

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-xfer',
  templateUrl: './xfer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./xfer.component.css']
})
export class XferComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  sub: any

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route
      .queryParams
      .subscribe(params => {
        localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({
          token : params['jwt']
        }))
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  }

}
```

My goal is to call this URL from another app like this:

```
http://myapp.com/x?jwt=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ
```

Since my home page, and the rest of the app, is using an `AuthGuard`, prompting for login would happen next **if it is needed**.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably just use [ActivatedRouteSnapshot](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRouteSnapshot), grap params and redirect right out from constructor like this:

```ts
constructor(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, router: Router)
{
  localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({
      token : route.params.jwt
    }));
  router.navigate(['/']);
}
```